# buildozer: crashed with 'env': env must be a dict

Tags: python, compiling, android

The error is that 'env':env must be a dict. I believe I have upgraded buildozer and my env. My buildozer was installed using pip3, and my code is for python 3. Also, I used the module plyer in my source code, I don't know if that's the case, but if I just build kivy, then there's no error.

Please give some suggestions, solutions, or feedbacks!

Below is my main.py, buildozer.spec, and log (I deleted some because of the body size limit).

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from plyer import sms

Builder.load_string('''
<SmsInterface>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: sp(30)
        Label:
            text: 'Recipient:'
        TextInput:
            id: recipient
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: message.focus = True
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Message:'
        TextInput:
            id: message
    IntentButton:
        sms_recipient: recipient.text
        sms_message: message.text
        text: 'Send SMS'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: sp(40)
        on_release: self.send_sms()
''')


class SmsInterface(BoxLayout):
    pass


class IntentButton(Button):
    sms_recipient = StringProperty()
    sms_message = StringProperty()

    def send_sms(self, *args):
        sms.send(recipient=self.sms_recipient, message=self.sms_message)


class SmsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SmsInterface()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SmsApp().run()
```

buildozer.spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Plyer sms Test

# (str) Package name
package.name = plyersms

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
#version.regex = __version__ = '(.*)'
#version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
version = 0.1

# (list) Application requirements
requirements = plyer,kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0


#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = SEND_SMS

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 14

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#android.minapi = 8

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# List as sections
#
# You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
# Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
# Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
# Instead of doing:
#
#     [app]
#     source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
# This can be translated into:
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns]
#     license
#     data/audio/*.wav
#     data/images/original/*
#


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Profiles
#
# You can extend section / key with a profile
# For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
# HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
# and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#     [app@demo]
#     title = My Application (demo)
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#     images/hd/*
#
# Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#     buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

log:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run

[INFO]:    Copying pyjnius java class to classes build dir
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python3-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running cp -a jnius/src/org /home/yd/D...(and 84 more)
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Postbuilding android for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Postbuilding kivy for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    # Installing pure Python modules
[INFO]:    *** PYTHON PACKAGE / PROJECT INSTALL STAGE ***
[INFO]:    The requirements (certifi, plyer) don't have recipes, attempting to install them with pip
[INFO]:    If this fails, it may mean that the module has compiled components and needs a recipe.
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build
[INFO]:    -> running virtualenv --python=python3 venv
[INFO]:    Upgrade pip to latest version                                       
[INFO]:    -> running bash -c source venv/bin/activat...(and 23 more)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1199, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 671, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 155, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 209, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 605, in build_recipes
    ignore_setup_py=ignore_project_setup_py
  File "/home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 791, in run_pymodules_install
    ), _env=copy.copy(base_env))
  File "/home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 179, in shprint
    output = command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1474, in __call__
    extracted_call_args, kwargs = self._extract_call_args(kwargs)
  File "/home/yd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1377, in _extract_call_args
    raise TypeError("Invalid special arguments:\n\n%s\n" % exc_msg)
TypeError: Invalid special arguments:

  'env': env must be a dict. Got environ({'GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS': 'JS ERROR;JS LOG', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'USER': 'yd', 'TEXTDOMAIN': 'im-config', 'XDG_SEAT': 'seat0', 'SSH_AGENT_PID': '1163', 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE': 'x11', 'SHLVL': '1', 'QT4_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'HOME': '/home/yd', 'OLDPWD': '/home/yd/Desktop', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE': 'ubuntu', 'GTK_MODULES': 'gail:atk-bridge', 'ANDROIDMINAPI': '21', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus', 'COLORTERM': 'truecolor', 'IM_CONFIG_PHASE': '2', 'LOGNAME': 'yd', 'GTK_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', '_': '/home/yd/.local/bin/buildozer', 'ANDROIDAPI': '27', 'USERNAME': 'yd', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': '1', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'ANDROIDNDK': '/home/yd/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b', 'WINDOWPATH': '1', 'PATH': '/home/yd/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin:/home/yd/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/yd/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/yd/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b:/home/yd/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools:/home/yd/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/yd/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin', 'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local/COMPUTER:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1027,unix/COMPUTER:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1027', 'XDG_MENU_PREFIX': 'gnome-', 'GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN': '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/32290487_4474_4053_b800_c94f4e7d0d39', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'ubuntu:GNOME', 'ANDROIDSDK': '/home/yd/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP': 'ubuntu', 'XMODIFIERS': '@im=ibus', 'GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE': ':1.62', 'XAUTHORITY': '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'QT_ACCESSIBILITY': '1', 'GDMSESSION': 'ubuntu', 'PACKAGES_PATH': '/home/yd/.buildozer/android/packages', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'TEXTDOMAINDIR': '/usr/share/locale/', 'GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT': 'stderr', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1', 'XDG_VTNR': '1', 'QT_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'PWD': '/home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android', 'CLUTTER_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg', 'VTE_VERSION': '5202', 'PYTHONPATH': '/home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/plyersms'})

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=plyersms --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=plyer,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/yd/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     USERNAME = 'yd'
#     XDG_VTNR = '1'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
#     USER = 'yd'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/32290487_4474_4053_b800_c94f4e7d0d39'
#     PWD = '/home/yd/Desktop/test'
#     HOME = '/home/yd'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1163'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     WINDOWPATH = '1'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.62'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LOGNAME = 'yd'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/yd/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/yd/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/COMPUTER:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1027,unix/COMPUTER:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1027'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/yd/Desktop'
#     _ = '/home/yd/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/yd/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/yd/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/yd/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Hey, I am assuming you are running this on a virtual machine? Have you installed kivmb on that machine?

Comment: Yes, I am running this on Virtual Box. Can you explain kivmb more? Is there anything I need to do after installing kvm? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I meant kivmob. Have you installed kivmob onto your virtual box?

Comment: No, but can you explain how kivmob is related to this issue? I searched it up a bit, it's just putting ads inside a kivy application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue, and was able to resolve it with some minor tweaks to some buildozer code:

1. Navigate to your app directory
2. CD to: `.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid`
3. Open up `build.py`
4. On lines 791, 797, and 841, you should see `_env=copy.copy(base_env)`.
   Replace all instances of that with `_env=dict(copy.copy(base_env))`

So, it should look about like this:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W662i.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMGTT.png)

Then, save and rebuild as normal. Good luck!

Comment: It worked! I'm glad that you looked through the build.py and found its errors; it saved me a lot of time.Thank you!

Comment: @Camden Senneff - Thank you! It turns out this has been fixed in the p4a develop branch ([more info](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/2170#issuecomment-623664851)) but the fix has not yet been released.